# VBA Dim Object error

Tags: excel, vba

If I Run

```
Sub test()

Dim Template_Excel_Instance As excel.application
Set Template_Excel_Instance = CreateObject("excel.application")

End Sub
```

my code breaks with an error "Automation Error, Library not registered"

If I run

```
Sub test()

Dim Template_Excel_Instance As object
Set Template_Excel_Instance = CreateObject("excel.application")

End Sub
```

It runs fine. Is there any way to fix this? Reason I ask is that this issue only affects one PC, despite having the same references as all other PCs. The first error is not coming up anywhere else

Comment: @QHarr Yes that's the issue - it is working on most PCs just not one, I am trying to understand why.

Comment: Registry issue, perhaps?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: No, the registry is fine. Trust me, the Office installer works very well.

Comment: Any ideas how to investigate.. pretty clueless on how to get this fixed.

Comment: If run within excel-vba why not `Dim Template_Excel_Instance As New Excel.Application` ?

Comment: @user33484: Chill out, use late binding. Like I say in my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd rather not change the code as this is run across multiple computers and would rather get the same reference in this computer.

Comment: @user33484: Once you've written your VBA, changing from early to late binding is surprisingly trivial.

Comment: @Bathsheba I understand it's not difficult to do, but I don't have permission to fix it right now, and would like to just get it working.

Comment: @user33484: In that case, go over to the offending pc, open the VBA, select all, cut, then paste. That forces a recompilation. If that doesn't fix it then you might need to remove and re-add the reference. Of course then though that PC has a different version of the application to everyone else.

Comment: @bathsheba Do you mean cut and paste the code? Just tried and didn't work. Tried repairing excel too - no luck.

Comment: I wouldn't suspect anything wrong with Excel, yet anyway. Out of interest, if you type that code in that version of Excel (from scratch, in a new workbook), then what happens?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes - complete from scratch

Comment: My hunch is correct then. It’s due to different excel versions.

Answer (score 3):

Does that PC have a different version of Excel?

The problem is with `As Excel.Application`. If you don't have the appropriate *reference* defined, then the VBA compiler will not recognise the type. Yes, VBA does have a compilation step. If you do have the reference defined, then this is sensitive to the application version (just the *major* part of the application version I think), so is therefore inherently non-portable.

In your latter example, you are using *late binding*, so only COM object registration is required, not any specific library to be added to your project. For portability, this is the way to go.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, so even though Excel Object library will be there by default it will fail with Excel.Application? So this is a bigger scope? What would the appropriate reference be?

Comment: What is the correct reference to have defined? They seem identical across both systems

Comment: @Bathsheba Wow..so it even throws when different object library version. One to watch for.

Comment: "I have this down as a serious flaw in COM", I disagree.  If a user upgrades their Excel they'd expect the type library to advance from Excel 12 to Excel 13.

Comment: @SMeaden: I'll defer to your better judgement - it's been many years since I studied COM in depth. That said though, it does break the VBA project references when using early binding - and it is tempting to think of VBA as uncompiled source code.

Comment: Same version of excel

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you tried repairing the install?

Secondly, is there a reason you are instantiating a second instance of Excel?

Thirdly, let's get a grip on what is happening, please run this code and report back.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestWhatVersionDoesCreateObjectReturn()

    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Debug.Print obj.Version
End Sub

Sub TestWhatOtherVersionsAreCreatable()


    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 7 To 16

        Dim obj As Object
        Set obj = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next '///set break on unhadnled errors
        Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application." & CStr(lLoop))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not obj Is Nothing Then Debug.Print obj.Version


    Next

End Sub
```

Also, look for multiple installations of Excel.  The code at this [blog page](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/03/using-wmi-to-query-registry-for-type.html) will read your registry and write the results to an Excel worksheet.  You say you have repaired the install but there might be other Excel installations interfering.  The code in that blog will highlight multiple Excel installs.

Ok, from your feedback you say all the Excel libraries version return 14, implying no multi version installs.  Hmmm, we ought to consider that actually the library that error is complaining about isn't Excel but a dependency.

Other possible leads

[Social MSDN - automation error. Library not registered - solved by cleaning registry of legacy "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" keys](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d35f6852-8770-4503-8428-4a7040b654cd/suddenly-automation-error-library-not-registered?forum=isvvba#05745a54-d79f-4e0b-b785-1576038462f4)

Comment: All comes out with version 14.0 and I have tried repairing

Comment: I have added some more ideas

Comment: Thanks - I get an error after copying the code from the link: "Automation Error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Comment: ok,l sorry that registry code did not work, it is very useful for reporting in the contents of the registry, and now you'll have to poke around manually using RegEdit.Exe.  I have found an MSDN link which might help.  Can you report the 32-bit 64 bit dimension in your question text?  I mean is problem machine different.